# Asterisk replacement for multi-line/multi-phone/all ring Nortel system?

Tags: voip, telephony, asterisk, telecommunication

I'm trying to replace an aging Nortel phone system with an Asterisk based system. The existing system work something like this:

```
    Phone 1-          -Line 1
    Phone 2--        --Line 2
    Phone 3---Server---Line 3
    Phone 4--        --Line 4
    Phone 5-          -Line 5
```

People from the outside call Line 1's number. The server then rings all of the phones, which show a call on Line 1. Someone picks up a phone, and they are connected with the caller. If the main number is busy, and someone else calls it, it is routed to Line 2, or line 3, etc. I plan to put in VoIP hardphones and an Asterisk server, then use a Digium card to connect the existing POTS lines to the Asterisk server. How would I accomplish something like this in Asterisk? Specific config examples would help.

Comment: Will be using plain Asterisk or are you going to put in a Web GUI of some sort ? It's a lot easier to configure using something like FreePBX, you can setup ring groups etc using the GUI pretty easily - but I don't remember how to do it off the top of my head...

Comment: I'll look into FreePBX (I've never heard of it before.) Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use trixbox or elastix. Google for manuals.

Also it can be helpfull read ORelly "Asterisk the future of telephony"

For setup you lines you need fxo&fxs sip adapters or card.